# Why does a subshell of an interactive shell run as an interactive shell?

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

With my Bash session, I run this command:

```
(echo $$ $BASHPID $-)
```

and I get

```
22108 25602 himBH
```

So, my subshell runs as an interactive shell.

If I try to run the same command in background

```
(echo $$ $BASHPID $-) &
```

I get the same output.  Why does the subshell run as an interactive shell?

Comment: According to a UNIX expert, if the shell was started as interactive, it remains so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subshell *inherits* all the characteristics of the parent, and that includes settings.  That's part of the definition of a subshell.  It makes no difference if it is running in foreground or background - jobs can be swapped between foreground and background quite easily.

A non-subshell will not be interactive.  For example, if I put

```
(echo $$ $BASHPID $-)
```

into a script called `gash.sh` and call it from a non-interactive shell:

```
$ bash gash.sh
73879 73880 hB
```

But if I source the file, then it is a subshell of an interactive shell:

```
$ . ./gash.sh
1130 himBH
```

Comment: This sucks as it makes `set -u` behave differently. If a variable does not exist and the function errors out, it won't exit with a non zero status.

Comment: There are no functions involved here.   Can you give an example?

Comment: ```
meow() {(set -u; echo "$BAR")}
meow; echo $?
```

Comment: @nhooyr: of course that won't retain the `set -u`, you are running it in a child process.  If you omit the subshell parentheses `meow() { set -u; echo "$BAR"; }  ` then it will exit at once.

Comment: The point isn't retaining `set -u`, the problem is that the exit status isn't propagated. i.e the function itself exits with status 0.