# SIGTSTP (Ctrl-Z) stops only the subshell, but the parent shell keeps running - interactive bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, subshell, interactive-shell, job-control

in an interacive bash shell, i want to call a function,
which starts a subshell, to run some bash code

```
f() { echo a; ( sleep 5; ); echo z $?; }; f
```

i need the subshell to catch `exit 1` from the bash code,
so my interacive bash shell keeps running.
see also [Is there a TRY CATCH command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash)

the code in the subshell is a long-running process, for example `sleep 5`

problem: when i call the function and send SIGTSTP (Ctrl-Z),
then only the subshell is stopped, and the main function keeps running

expected: SIGTSTP (Ctrl-Z) should stop both the main function and the subshell,
and SIGCONT (fg) should continue running both

workaround: [build bash with --disable-job-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137915/disabling-job-control-in-bash-ctrl-z),
because `set +m` does not work, and `stty susp undef` is too limiting

```
$ f() { echo a; ( sleep 5; ); echo z $?; }; f
a
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ( sleep 5 )
z 148

$ fg
( sleep 5 )

$
```

the return code 148 means 128 + 20, and 20 == SIGTSTP
see also [Exit status ($?) of 148 upon Ctrl+Z](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62173/exit-status-of-148-upon-ctrlz)

with `wait -f %1` in the main function,
the main function hangs, and i have to interrupt (Ctrl-C)

`%1` works here, because there is only one job

```
$ f() { echo a; ( sleep 5; ); wait -f %1; echo z $?; }; f
a
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ( sleep 5 )
bash: warning: wait_for_job: job 1 is stopped
^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^C

$
```

with `trap "" SIGTSTP` in the subshell, the SIGTSTP (Ctrl-Z) is ignored

```
$ f(){ echo a; ( trap "" SIGTSTP; sleep 5; ); echo z $?; }; f
a
^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Zz 0

$
```

with `trap handle_tstp SIGTSTP` in the subshell,
the interactive shell hangs on SIGTSTP (Ctrl-Z)

```
$ f(){ echo a; ( s() { echo s; }; trap s SIGTSTP; sleep 5; ); echo z $?; }; f
a
^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

`trap handle_tstp SIGTSTP` in the main function has no effect

```
f(){ s() { echo s; }; trap s SIGTSTP; echo a; ( sleep 5; ); echo z $?; }; f
```

`kill -SIGTSTP $$` in the main function has no effect,
so the main function cannot stop itself

```
f(){ echo a; ( sleep 5; ); kill -SIGTSTP $$; echo z $?; }; f
```

`$$` versus `$BASHPID`, parent shell versus subshell

```
$ f(){ echo par $$ $BASHPID; ( echo sub $$ $BASHPID; ) }; f
par 613627 613627
sub 613627 613652
```

more tricks i tried... but the SIGTSTP always stops only a part, and the other part keeps running in the background. i also tried to trap the SIGTSTP to manually `kill -SIGTSTP $subshell_pid` but the trap fails to catch the SIGTSTP

with this, SIGTSTP is ignored

> `r() { echo $$.b; while read -r L; do echo "$$.b $L"; done <$1; echo $$.d; }; f() { echo $$.a; r <( for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo $BASHPID.c.$i; sleep 1; done; ); echo $$.z $?; }; f`

with these, SIGTSTP stops only the foreground process

> `r() { echo $$.b; cat $1 | while read -r L; do echo "$$.b $L"; done; echo $$.d; }; f() { echo $$.a; r <( for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo $BASHPID.c.$i; sleep 1; done; ); echo $$.z $?; }; f`

> `r() { echo $$.b; cat $1; echo $$.d; }; f() { echo $$.a; r <( for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo $BASHPID.c.$i; sleep 1; done; ); echo $$.z $?; }; f`

> `r() { echo $$.b; t() { echo trap; }; trap t SIGTSTP; cat $1 | while read -r L; do echo "$$.b $L"; done; echo $$.d; }; f() { echo $$.a; r <( for ((i=0;i<5;i++)); do echo $BASHPID.c.$i; sleep 1; done; ); echo $$.z $?; }; f`

see also: [Why does a subshell of an interactive shell run as an interactive shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340907/why-does-a-subshell-of-an-interactive-shell-run-as-an-interactive-shell)

> A subshell inherits all the characteristics of the parent

Comment: A function ***is not*** a subshell!! You cout try to hit *`Ctrl+Z`*, after running: `bash -c 'f() { echo a; ( sleep 5; ); echo z $?;};f'`

Comment: `( sleep 5; )` is the subshell. i need an \*interactive\* shell